# How to edit PHP configuration command in MAMP to exclude intl package

Tags: php, mamp, intl

I am using MAMP Pro 3.0.5 to run Apache/PHP on my computer, running OS X (Yosemite DP2). I just installed an old project on my server, but I get an conflict with the `intl` package that is now being initialized (I guess this was not on my previous setup).

The `phpinfo()` provides me with the fact, that `intl` is laoded through the configuration command, which ends:

```
 '--with-mcrypt=shared,/Applications/MAMP/Library' '--with-openssl' '--enable-zip' '--with-iconv=/Applications/MAMP/Library' '--enable-opcache' '--enable-cgi'
 '--enable-intl'
 '--with-icu-dir=/Applications/MAMP/Library' '--with-tidy=shared'
```

I cannot figure out where to edit this, so I can remove `--enable-intl`?

**Update 1**

There is not reference to `intl` in php.ini:

[image]
[image]

**Update 2**

```
$ /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.5.10/bin/php --ini

Configuration File (php.ini) Path: /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.5.10/conf
Loaded Configuration File:         /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.5.10/conf/php.ini
Scan for additional .ini files in: (none)
Additional .ini files parsed:      (none)
```

Comment: You don't need to recompile php (the above code block is showing the command used to configure php when it was built) - just find the php.ini file in use and the reference to `intl.so` and comment it out.

Comment: There is no reference to intl.so in php.ini.

Comment: it should be in php.ini or in a file it loads/references. see the output of `$ php --ini`.

Comment: @AD7six As you see in Update 1 (post) there is no reference in php.ini, and neither does the extension exist in the `extensions` folder.

I can not do a `$ php --ini` as the PHP version in Terminal (OS X) is not the same as the one being used by MAMP.

Comment: `$ php --ini` is now included as Update 2.

Comment: See "loaded configuration file" in the screenshot - you're looking at the wrong ini file. Showing the cli output isn't relevant since it's also a different ini file.

Comment: The outcome is the same in the loaded configuration file. Furthermore, it is simply a copy of the one I outputted above.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56189/discussion-between-c-jespersen-and-ad7six).